# Android's AudioRecord uses built-in microphone instead of headset microphone

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

An Android I am using `AudioRecord` to record the sound from the microphone from a headset that is connected to the 3.5 mm headset jack of my device (Samsung Galaxy S5). The device detects the headset, because it shows the notification of the headset and it plays sounds from the earphones.

However, the device uses the built-in microphone instead of the microphone from the headset, but not always: sometimes it does use the microphone from the headset, which is what I want.

So it seems to be that there are two states:

1. use built-in microphone
2. use headset microphone

and occasionally it moves from one state to the other. But I have no clue which events lead to these state changes.

How can I make sure the device always uses the headset microphone?

Some properties:

- using `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC` as audio source
- the application does not fail or show any errors
- all possible return codes and states are checked
- Android Studio 1.2.2, Android 22
- Samsung Galaxy S5, Android 5.0